# Live video broadcasting through webcam to receivers with broadcast queuing

Tags: php, http-live-streaming, youtube-livestreaming-api

I got a project where i am working on making live broadcasts to users. I am basically PHP guy and i want to know about it. In this application PHP web application, user will log in and start a new broadcast through its webcam. The broadcast started should be viewed by the users who enter that particular channel. And user can also skip the live streaming and can move to next. What things are required in this case from PHP side?. What are the key things from PHP side else i have to use for live streaming that will access the webcam at receiver side too?.

Answer (score 1):

Creating Live Event and Live Broadcast API objects is language-independent, just use YouTube's [Live Streaming HTTP API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/) (rather than their data API).  Read through the [Core Concepts](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started) and [Life of a Broadcast](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/life-of-a-broadcast) guides.

Your flow might look something like this:

1. Authenticate the user using OAuth 2 and their Google Account.
2. Ensure the user's YouTube account has live streaming enabled (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32889887/2415822) for more info on that flow).
3. Set up and schedule your Live Broadcast object.
4. Start your video encoder and create a Live Stream Object.
5. Bind your Live Stream to your Live Broadcast.
6. Test to verify your video from your video encoder/webcam is hitting YouTube's ingestion endpoint.
7. Set your Live Broadcast to Live.
8. At the conclusion of your event, set your Live Broadcast to Ended.

Note that setting up your encoder is on you.  Asking "How do I create an RTMP video encoder in PHP" is too broad of a question for Stack Overflow.